# Visibility from an ObservableInt in a ViewModel not showing up

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding

I have a basic `Activity` with a `View` and a `ViewModel`. I am using DataBinding library.

I need to update the visibility of a `TextView` from the `ViewModel`.

Here is how I setup my `Activity` :

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Helper classes
    private var binding : ActivityHomeBinding? = null
    private var viewModel = HomeViewModel()

    // ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home)

        binding?.viewModel = viewModel

        // ...

        viewModel.setNoContact()
    }

    // ...

}
```

Here is how my `HomeViewModel` looks like :

```
class HomeViewModel {

    val contactsListVisibility = ObservableInt(View.VISIBLE)
    val loadingVisibility = ObservableInt(View.VISIBLE)
    val noContactVisibility = ObservableInt(View.VISIBLE)

    // ...

    fun setNoContact() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Current no contacts visibility = ${noContactVisibility.get()}")
        contactsListVisibility.set(View.GONE)
        loadingVisibility.set(View.GONE)
        noContactVisibility.set(View.VISIBLE)
        Log.d(TAG, "Should set no contacts visibility to ${noContactVisibility.get()}")

    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "HomeViewModel"
    }
```

And here is my `View` :

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.ft_hangouts.home_activity.HomeViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        tools:context=".home_activity.HomeActivity">

        <!-- ... -->
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_contact"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.noContactVisibility}"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            style="@style/BasicTextStyle"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- ... -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

The path to my `ViewModel` in the xml layout is correct. The link is done, when I Ctrl + click it, I am brought to my `HomeViewModel`.

However, the "No Contact" `TextView` is never showing up.

Here is the result I get :

[image: No contact TextView is not visible]

And here is the result expected :

[image: No contact TextView is visible]

When looking at the logs, I have :

```
D/HomeViewModel: Current no contacts visibility = 8
    Should set no contacts visibility to 0
```

So there is no reason the `TextView` is not displayed. I am forgetting something ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you found the solution yet? and I don't think you should do any operations of UI in viewmodel..

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati nope, still nothing...

Comment: so I am assuming that you are getting contacts from somewhere, and when those contacts are 0, you wanna show "No contact" Textview right? I just ran your code and I am getting No Contact textview..

Comment: That is correct. This is strange... I am going to test again this evening,

Comment: Could you just add a variable type in which you are storing your contacts? there are multiple ways to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I have tried adding dummy data to test this. Assuming you have an ArrayList of contacts like this..

```
     val contactList: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf()
```

and I have added dummy data for contacts so you can test yourself. Usually you will get this data from a service or contact app.

`HomeViewModel`

```
 fun setDummyContact(isAddYes: Boolean){
        if(isAddYes){
            contactList.add(7673443334)
            contactList.add(2233444512)
            contactList.add(1233455623)
        }
    }
```

You can set data from your `HomeActivity` like this...

```
        viewModel.setDummyContact(false) // for no contact data
**OR**  viewModel.setDummyContact(true)  // add contacts -
```

You can simply do the following to handle Visibility of `TextView` based on your ***contactList data***.

1. Add import of View to your datatype

```
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.ft_hangouts.home_activity.HomeViewModel" />
    </data>
```

and then add this to your `No Contact TextView`

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.contactList.size() > 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

So you **don't need to add any function or Boolean value to handle visibility**. It is more cleaner and better solution because you don't need to additional variable to handle visibility of the textView. You can do the same for any other View you would like to show or hide.